# Alloy - Illegal Relational Join

Tags: join, typeerror, alloy

This are my current signature declarations:

```
    abstract sig Human {}
    sig Male, Female extends Human {}
    sig Group {inGroup: set Human}
```

I want to be able to find out if there are more `Male` than `Female` in the `Group`. I have been trying to use:

```
    #Group.Male > #Group.Female
```

However, this doesn't work as the left type is `Human` and the right type is `Male`/`Female` and therefore says it is not a legal relational join. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use intersection (&) not selection.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "the group"? A signature denotes a set of objects, so there are possibly several groups here.